# Updating filling in blanks on SQL table based on csv

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a small project at my office to do some clean up on our customers table stored in SQL Server and a similar one stored in PostgreSQL. Basically we found many customers have one or several columns that have 0 or are blank and need to be filled in. Our plan is to first gather all of the data for the 0 or blank columns and fill in the csv, and then somehow script it to fill in the blank columns for each customer.

Below is an example of what the current table looks like with 0s and blank columns. It's random as to which column or columns need to be filled in for a given customer (the one thing we always have is the customer's username).

```
    username    emp_num title      email                  phone 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    jsmith      0       Manager    jsmith@somewhere.com 
    kjones      112222  Clerk                             111-222-3333
    wgarcia     0                  wgarcis@domain.com     444-555-6666
```

We would be filling in anything with "0" with a 6 digit number and any blanks would have values filled in on the csv.

Question is, after I have a completed csv with all customer info, how might I go about:

1. loading the csv into SQL; and
2. scripting this to compare the csv file against the existing customer table and fill in only what's missing?  (i.e. 0s and blanks).

Can anyone share example SQL queries to get me started? (How might it need to be approached differently for PostgreSQL?)

TIA,
Chris

Comment: Is this a one time thing? How many customers do you have? If you're doing this once and only have a few thousand simple string building in Excel is often the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Update off a join to the correct customer table like this:

```
update a 
set a.emp_num=b.emp_num
from currenttable a join customer b on a.username=b.username
where a.emp_num in (0,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is a one time task. You can do this very easily with some simple string building using Excel or another spreadsheet application. It won't be reusable, but it's often the quickest solution.

That said it isn't going to work if you have a very large number of customers, but it'll do the trick for several thousand.

**Excel Formula**

```
="UPDATE YourTable SET emp_num = " & B2 & ", title = '" & C2 & "', email = '" & D2 & "', phone = '" & E2 & "' WHERE username = '" & A2 & "'"
```

Simply copy the formula to all the rows in your csv, and execute the generated queries.